# Why does EntityAspect.RemoveFromManager not remove completely?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, devforce

I am using Silverlight 4 and DevForce 6.1.11.0

I have some POCO classes that implement EntityAspect.

I use WebClient to get these entities from different devices. These devices do not have a DevForce server.
When adding the entities to the entity manager, I first check that a entity with the key does not exist in cache using `entityManager.FindEntities<PocoSomeEntity>(EntityState.AllButDetached)`. Then I create the entity and add it like this:

```
entityManager.AddEntity(entity);
entity.EntityAspect.AcceptChanges();
```

I can add, modify and delete entities and save them back to the devices - no problems so far.

Lately I implemented a "clear cache" using `entity.EntityAspect.RemoveFromManager(true);`
This seemed to work expect if I delete a entity (`EntityAspect.Delete()`), then remove it from the manager and then try to load it back in. When calling `EntityAspect.AcceptChanges()` on the reloaded entity, it throws a "already exists" exception.

How do I workaround this issue?

EDIT

It is `AddEntity()` that throws the exception.

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityGroup.AddToKeyMap(EntityAspect aspect)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityGroup.AddEntityCore(EntityAspect aspect)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityGroup.AddAttachedEntity(EntityAspect aspect, EntityState entityState)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.AttachEntityAspect(EntityAspect aspect, EntityState entityState)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.AttachEntity(Object entity, EntityState entityState)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.AddEntity(Object entity)
   at ...
```

My entity has a composite key.
I searched the cache but I found nothing:

```
// returns nothing
var instancesInManager = entityManager.FindEntities<PocoSomeEntity>(EntityState.AllButDetached).Where(i => i.p_key1 == 41 && i.p_key2 == 5448);
// returns nothing
var detachedInstancesInManager = entityManager.FindEntities<PocoSomeEntity>(EntityState.Detached).Where(i => i.p_key1 == 41 && i.p_key2 == 5448);
```

I also search without the key but found nothing that could explain this behavior:

```
// returns instances, but none have keys with zeros or the key that I am looking for.
var instancesInManager = entityManager.FindEntities<PocoSomeEntity>(EntityState.AllButDetached);
// returns no results
var detachedInstancesInManager = entityManager.FindEntities<PocoSomeEntity>(EntityState.Detached);
```

EDIT2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using IdeaBlade.Core.DomainServices;
using IdeaBlade.EntityModel;
using IbVal = IdeaBlade.Validation;

namespace ServerModel
{
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class PocoSomeEntity : IKnownType, IHasPocoEntityAspect, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public PocoSomeEntity () { }

        private int m_key1;

        [Key]
        public int p_key1
        {
            get { return m_key1; }
            set { m_key1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("p_key1"); }
        }

        private int m_key2;
        [Key]
        public int p_key2
        {
            get { return m_key2; }
            set { m_key2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("p_key2"); }
        }

...

        #region IHasPocoEntityAspect Members

        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityAspect EntityAspect
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// This interface implementation is needed if you want EntityManager to automatically listen
        /// to any property change.
        /// </summary>

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in testing.  The exception will be thrown when doing the AddEntity() if the key already exists in the EM cache.  Check the value of the EntityKey prior to doing the add - if it's something like 0 or a tempid that may help narrow down the problem, or give us more information to diagnose it.

Comment: I added more details to the post. Before doing AddEntity, the entity has no EntityAspect and I can not examine the EntityKey. After AddEntity, it throws the exception. After this, the EntityKey is right but the entity is detached.

Comment: Is the entity key shown in the error message the correct key?  I'm still wondering if it's possibly been set to zeroes or assigned a negative ID by a temp id generator.  If it looks as expected, you can also construct an EntityKey from the correct key values and then call em.FindEntity(entityKey) to see if that finds a match in cache.

Comment: Yes, the key in the error message is the correct key. If I call FindEntity() with the correct key ({PocoSomeEntity:41,5448}), it returns a detached entity with key: {PocoSomeEntity:0,0} ???

Comment: What does PocoSomeEntity look like?  Can you post its definition?

Comment: Added class description to post.

Comment: Is there no way of taking a detached entity and completely delete it from memory?

Comment: Normally detached entities are removed from the cache.  DF keeps a dictionary of entities keyed by EntityKey, and when an entity is removed from the manager this entry is removed from the dictionary too.  So the behavior you're seeing is not expected. If you can send me a small repro sample I can look at it further.

Comment: Maybe I will make a repro. In the mean time I posted an answer with a workaround. If I find a detached entity with FindEntity(), I re-populate its properties and add it back into the manager.

Comment: @KimJohnson I have made a repro. Where can I send it?

Comment: Thanks, Danjal.  My ideablade address, kimj...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've uncovered a bug in the SL version of DevForce.  The issue is in how DF handles the EntityKey on an entity, as it doesn't set the underlying property value for certain entity states and entity versions.  Here, despite doing an Add followed by AcceptChanges, DF has still not set the backing field for the EntityKey, which causes the odd behavior later on.

There are a couple of workarounds which might be easier than the Find logic you've implemented.

- The first is to use Attach rather than Add/AcceptChanges for these POCO entities.  The code path DF follows when the entity is attached as "Unchanged" does ensure the EntityKey is set properly.

  ```
  manager.AttachEntity(entity);
  ```
- If the use case requires that entities be in an "Added" state, the other workaround is to invoke the EntityKey getter after doing an AcceptChanges, which ensures the EntityKey backing field is set correctly. Eg,

  ```
   manager.AddEntity(entity);
   entity.EntityAspect.AcceptChanges();
   var ek = entity.EntityAspect.EntityKey;
  ```

Comment: You saved my day! I went for the AttachEntity workaround and it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to double check with FindEntity(). If it exists, then re-populate its properties and add it back into manager.

```
// Check if entity already exists in manager
var instancesInManager = entityManager.FindEntities<PocoSomeEntity>(EntityState.AllButDetached).Where(i => i.p_key1==key1 && i.p_key2==key2);
var entity = instancesInManager.FirstOrDefault();
if (entity == null)
{
        PocoSomeEntity i;

        // Double check if entity really exists in manager :)
        var doubleCheck = entityManager.FindEntity(new EntityKey(typeof(PocoSomeEntity), key1, key2));
        if (doubleCheck != null)
        {
                i = (doubleCheck as PocoSomeEntity);
        }
        else
                // If it does not exists, then we can create it
                i = new PocoSomeEntity();

        i.p_key1 = key1;
        i.p_key2 = key2;

        // populate or re-populate entity properties
        ...

        entityManager.AddEntity(i);
        i.EntityAspect.AcceptChanges();
}
```

EDIT

The workaround does not work if I delete two or more entities of the same type.